# Convergence of summable Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f$ be a function on $[0,2\pi)$ satisfying $(\hat{f}(k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z}),$ where $$\hat{f}(k)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)e^{-ikt}dt.$$

Is it always true that 
$$f(x)=\sum_\mathbb{Z}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}, \text{ for almost every } x\in [0,2\pi)?$$

Which condition on $f$ guarantees above?

$(\hat{f}(k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}  \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$ implies that the Fourier series converges uniformly and absolutely to $f$ and $f$ is continuous. So am I required to assume that $f$ is continuous?

(I know there are some constant missing that normalises the transformation. Please ignore that)

Comment: It really depends on what you want to assume for $f$ (thus for the transform), if $f$ is $L^1$ it is false (Kolmogorov), if $f$ is in $L^p$ for $p>1$ it is true (Carleson-Hunt). So it's delicate.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking - The OP assumes that the sequence of Fourier coefficients is absolutely convergent, so the deep theorems you quote seem to be irrelevant.

Comment: Isn't the result true if $f\in L^1$ and $(\hat{f}(k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$? Why?

Comment: That is my point @uniquesolution. I guess the result will be true for any $f$ provided $(\hat{f}(k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$. What you think?

Comment: You want the Fourier coefficients to be defined, right. So you have to make some integrability assumption on $f$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks, I missed that. Even so, an assumption on $\hat{f}$ converts to an assumption on $f$, so the situation would still be delicate without assuming something grand (such as summability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True for any $f \in  L^{1}$ with $\hat {f} \in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z)$. Let $g(x)=\sum \hat {f} (k)e^{ikx}$. The series is uniformly convergent by M-test so $g$ is a  continuous periodic function. By uniform convergence we get $\int e^{-int} g(t)dt=\sum \hat {f} (k) \int e^{i(k-n) t} dt $ which shows that $\hat {f}=\hat {g}$. Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable this implies $f=g$ a.e. and hence $f=\sum \hat {f} (k)e^{ikx}$ a.e.

Comment: I understand for integrable function. Is it true for any function?

Comment: What is the definition of $\hat {f}$ if $f$ is 'any function '.

Comment: For any function that satisfies $(\hat{f}(k))_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: That does not make sense. Define $\hat {f}$.

Comment: Okay now i get your point. In order to define Fourier transform we need ta atleast assume that $f\in L^1$. That should be the maximum space. Am i right?

Comment: Yes,that is why  I am assuming that $f$ is integrable.